# Trying to summarize list in arcpy

Tags: cursor, arcpy

I have a list of xy points that I'm trying to sum together and identify the centroid, but it only uses the last value in the row. I'm trying to create a centroid for each state, Here's the code:

```
Total_X1 = 0
Total_Y1 = 0
TotalPop1 = 0
#Cat = "cali"
cntyName1 = "cnty"
stateName1 = "statename"
for row in cursor:

    #if row[0] >= : ### for condition that is met
    #if row[0]== []:
        TheStateName1 = row[0]
        thecntyName1 = row[4]
        idpoly1 = row[5]
        idobject1 = row[6]
        stateFIPS1 = row[7]
        countyFIPS1 = row[8]
        fips1 = row[9]
        fipSnum1 = row[10]
        fipsNumer1 = row[11]
        #totarea = row[12]
        XPoint = row [13]
        YPoint = row[14]


        #print Cat
        print TheStateName1
        print thecntyName1

        print row       ### do something with that value!

        Total_X1 +=  row[2] *row[3]
        print Total_X1


        Total_Y1 +=  row[1] *row[3]
        print Total_Y1


        TotalPop1 += row[3]
        print TotalPop1

    print ""        
    print "X is: " , Total_X1
    print "POP is: " , TotalPop1
    centroid_X1 = Total_X1/TotalPop1
    print "your x centroid is: ",centroid_X1
    print ""
    #print Cat
    print thecntyName1
    print TheStateName1
```

Any Suggestions, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cursor can only 'see' one row at a time, you have to pull info from that row and store it elsewhere.

```
loc_list = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ['X_coord', 'Y_coord'])
```

Will give you a list of X,Y tuples from your attribute table.

After that you've got multiple options for turning that list of tuples into a spatial dataset before calculating the mean - start by reading the ESRI documentation for [arcpy.Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/point.htm) and all the related topics linked, and go from there. If you have 10.3 or above you can use [Mean Center](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/mean-center.htm) once you have a point layer.

You'll probably get a wrong answer if you just take the mean of the X and Y without projecting first, so don't.